# Javascript - How to get the new window Referrer after Redirection

Tags: javascript, redirect, referrer

I am trying to solve an issue that although seems to have been answered several times, not any of the solutions work for me.
The scenario is when user presses a button to  redirect him to another page (of the same domain) and then when few actions have completed to be redirected to the initial again. So, at first place, I need to get the new referrer of the page that the user is redirected. I've tried solutions with new referrer or without referrer such as the following ones with no luck:

```
function a() {
  var ref = window.open("http://localhost:8080/ui/about"); 
  ref.addEventListener('loadstart',function(iABObject){
  alert("print something");
  ToDo(); 
}
```

or second solution

```
function a() {
  window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/ui/about";
  if(window.location.href.indexOf("localhost:8080/ui/about")>-1 ){ 
     alert("print something");
     ToDo();
  }
}
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Your question and code doesn’t make sense. Redirecting is a simple `window.location`, is that what you are asking?

Comment: Setting `href` will start to load a new page, anything after that in a script won't be executed.

Comment: Please look at my first attempt with the EventListener. I think this sample describes what I would like to do, which is when the second window opens the function ToDo() is called. But ToDo() is never called.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do something like this: 
pageA:

```
function onClickMyButton(){
    window.location = "pageB";
}
```

pageB:

```
... do some stuff
window.location = document.referrer;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think it is a very good approach, but in my case I do not want to put stuff on page B. From my search, I realized that the reason ToDo() is never called is that ref.addEventListener('loadstart',function(iABObject) requires a device API library which is not my case. So,the questions is formed into putting a listener on new window that captures the event onload.